# Shell script to download, compile and run Analog Clock in AEC

Tags: bash, shell, sh

As some of you know, I have made a programming language, called AEC, and written two compilers for it, one targetting x86 and other targetting WebAssembly. Recently, I have tried to write two shell scripts to download, compile and use those compilers, and run the Analog Clock example. I have put those two shell scripts [on my blog](https://flatassembler.github.io/AEC_specification.html#HowToCompile), and it is important for me that they run on as many computers as possible. Here is what I've made by now.
Shell script to use the AEC-to-x86 compiler:

```bash
mkdir ArithmeticExpressionCompiler
cd ArithmeticExpressionCompiler
if [ $(command -v wget > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ] # Check if "wget" exists, see those StackOverflow answers for more details:
                                                                                         # https://stackoverflow.com/a/75103891/8902065
                                                                                         # https://stackoverflow.com/a/75103209/8902065
then
  wget https://flatassembler.github.io/Duktape.zip
else
  curl -o Duktape.zip https://flatassembler.github.io/Duktape.zip
fi
unzip Duktape.zip
if [ $(command -v clang > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ] # We prefer "clang" to "gcc" because... what if somebody tries to run this in CygWin terminal? GCC will not work then, CLANG might.
then
  c_compiler="clang"
else
  c_compiler="gcc"
fi
$c_compiler -o aec aec.c duktape.c -lm # The linker that comes with recent versions of Debian Linux insists that "-lm" is put AFTER the source files, or else it outputs some confusing error message.
if [ "$OS" = "Windows_NT" ]
then
  ./aec analogClockForWindows.aec
  $c_compiler -o analogClockForWindows analogClockForWindows.s -m32
  ./analogClockForWindows
else
  ./aec analogClock.aec
  $c_compiler -o analogClock analogClock.s -m32
  ./analogClock
fi
```

Shell script to use the AEC-to-WebAssembly compiler:

```bash
if [ $(command -v git > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
then
  git clone https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly.git
  cd AECforWebAssembly
elif [ $(command -v wget > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
then
  mkdir AECforWebAssembly
  cd AECforWebAssembly
  wget https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
  unzip master.zip
  cd AECforWebAssembly-master
else
  mkdir AECforWebAssembly
  cd AECforWebAssembly
  curl -o AECforWebAssembly.zip -L https://github.com/FlatAssembler/AECforWebAssembly/archive/refs/heads/master.zip # Without the "-L", "curl" will store HTTP Response headers of redirects to the ZIP file instead of the actual ZIP file.
  unzip AECforWebAssembly.zip
  cd AECforWebAssembly-master
fi
if [ $(command -v g++ > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
then
  g++ -std=c++11 -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp # "-std=c++11" should not be necessary for newer versions of "g++". Let me know if it is, as that probably means I disobeyed some new C++ standard (say, C++23).
else
  clang++ -o aec AECforWebAssembly.cpp
fi
cd analogClock
../aec analogClock.aec
npx -p wabt wat2wasm analogClock.wat
if [ "$OS" = "Windows_NT" ] # https://stackoverflow.com/a/75125384/8902065
                            # https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/10cip05/comment/j4h9f0x/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3
then
  node_version=$(node.exe -v)
else # We are presumably running on an UNIX-like system, where storing output of some program into a variable works as expected.
  node_version=$(node -v)
fi
# "node -v" outputs version in the format "v18.12.1"
node_version=${node_version:1} # Remove 'v' at the beginning
node_version=${node_version%\.*} # Remove trailing ".*".
node_version=${node_version%\.*} # Remove trailing ".*".
node_version=$(($node_version)) # Convert the NodeJS version number from a string to an integer.
if [ $node_version -lt 11 ]
then
  echo "NodeJS version is lower than 11 (it is $node_version), you will probably run into trouble!"
fi
node analogClock
```

So, what do you think, how can I improve those shell scripts? The most important thing for me is that they run on as many computers as possible, simply by being copied-and-pasted into a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: neither script has a `#!` line to select a specific shell.  If it's intended to be portable, I recommend `#!/bin/sh`.  And set some options: I recommend using both `-u` and `-e` to simplify the error-handling.

---

This is an anti-pattern:

> ```
> [ $(command -v wget > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
> ```

There's no need to print out the exit status like that - just use it directly:

```
command -v wget > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

We have a lot of repetition, particularly of URLs.  Fix that using variables, so that it's easier to change the hosting.

---

All that said, I think it's probably better to use existing tools such as Autoconf, and include that in your repo so that users can simply `git clone && ./configure && make` in the usual manner without having to do something special for your sources.

You will probably want to supply a makefile pattern rule that matches `*.aec` files.

Answer (score 3):

> most important thing ... is that they run on as many computers as possible, simply by being copied-and-pasted into a terminal emulator.

Those scripts seem a little on the long side.

Which invites user error from coordinating a copy-n-paste
with a window scroll operation.
And the longer the pasting, the greater the chance
of buffer overrun. I habitually put long pastes
into Aquamacs and *then* ask Terminal.app to run
the resulting file, so final characters won't be lost.

No need to paste in the compilation instructions,
as that could be pushed down into a ZIPped script.

Some software distributors go with a one-liner, like

```
$ bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I've seen others go with `$ curl -s $URL | bash`.

Which brings us to the assumption of `bash`, rather than `sh`.
It's fine to make that assumption -- just explicitly document it.

---

The `$(command -v foo)` expression is an interesting one.

Personally I tend to run `which foo 2>&1 > /dev/null`
and examine the exit status `$?`,
but then I usually just target unix-like platforms.
You might at some point delegate to a split pair of scripts
for unix and for windows.
If running `foo` is harmless, e.g. `clang --version`,
then a possibly simpler approach is to just run it,
with redirect, and inspect `$?` to see whether it worked.

---

> ```
> $(node.exe -v)
> ```

Maybe `$(node -v)` would suffice, even on windows?

After all, we later run `node analogClock`.

---

Rather than "NodeJS version is lower than 11 ... you will probably run into trouble!",
you might want to put a stake in the ground and
refuse to run on 10. Either it's a supported and tested
configuration, or it's not.

Consider publishing a version matrix of test results,
showing combinations you *know* pass their automated tests.

Comment: *Maybe $(node -v) would suffice, even on windows?*

No, it would not. It would output the "stdout is not a tty" error message instead of the version number.

Comment: Piping arbitrary web content into a shell is not something to be encouraged.